# How to return items from a multi-dimensional list using regex search

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I looking for help with solving a problem in Python 3: 
using search with RE module in multi-dimensional list and after return chunk of data from the list

Here is example how far I am:

```
import re

# my search input
my_list = [["10","ten","bottles"],
          ["9","seven","bottles"], 
          ["8","eight","bottles"]]

# search input
def some_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            my_search = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(
                "ERROR: Please enter your account number \
                \nContinue...\n"
                )
        else:
            break
    return str(my_search)

# search for match
def find_my_input():
    search = some_input("Search >>> ")
    regex = re.compile(search)
    for item in my_list:
        new_list = filter(regex.match, my_list)
        if item == new_list: 
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Let's say my input is: `9`
and expected output is: `["9","seven","bottles"]`

Comment: Is this really a regex question? `"blah" in somestring` should be good enough. The rest is.. not that hard.

Comment: Is this is really proper answer? I was expecting something more than this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, first thing to mention is that `Regex` would not be appropriate here because you are not dealing with a `string` but with a `list` of strings, and that makes it much easier. Lets take a look at your question:

> Let's say my input is: 9 and expected output is: ["9","seven","bottles"]

You can achieve this in 3 lines of code:

```
for line in my_list: # iterate over your matrix
    if my_value in line: # if your list has your input
        return line # return that list
```

You can rewrite your functions and make it much easier and shorter. I might suggest to do it this way:

```
def some_input(data):
    try:
        search = input("Search>>> ")
        if not search.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("Digits expected, instead {}".format(search))
    except ValueError:
        #handle your exception 
        pass

    # search for your list
    for line in data:
        if search in line:
            return line
```

To test it, call `print(some_input(my_list))`. With the input of `10` I've got next output:

```
Search>>> 10
['10', 'ten', 'bottles']
```